# build word co-occurence edge list in R

Tags: r, text-mining, network-analysis

I have a chunk of sentences and I want to build the undirected edge list of word co-occurrence and see the frequency of every edge. I took a look at the `tm` package but didn't find similar functions. Is there some package/script I can use? Thanks a lot!

Note: A word doesn't co-occur with itself. A word which appears twice or more co-occurs with other words for only once in the same sentence.

DF:

```
sentence_id text
1           a b c d e
2           a b b e
3           b c d
4           a e
5           a
6           a a a
```

OUTPUT

```
word1 word2 freq
a     b     2
a     c     1
a     d     1
a     e     3
b     c     2
b     d     2
b     e     2
c     d     2
c     e     1
d     e     1
```

Comment: @TylerRinker thanks! Exactly the output should remain the same as line 5 has only 'a' and in line 6 'a' doesn't co-occur with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's convoluted so there's got to be a better approach:

```
dat <- read.csv(text="sentence_id, text
1,           a b c d e
2,           a b b e
3,           b c d
4,           a e", header=TRUE)


library(qdapTools); library(tidyr)
x <- t(mtabulate(with(dat, by(text, sentence_id, bag_o_words))) > 0)
out <- x %*% t(x)
out[upper.tri(out, diag=TRUE)] <- NA

out2 <- matrix2df(out, "word1") %>%
    gather(word2, freq, -word1) %>%
    na.omit() 

rownames(out2) <- NULL
out2

##    word1 word2 freq
## 1      b     a    2
## 2      c     a    1
## 3      d     a    1
## 4      e     a    3
## 5      c     b    2
## 6      d     b    2
## 7      e     b    2
## 8      d     c    2
## 9      e     c    1
## 10     e     d    1
```

**Base only solution**

```
out <- lapply(with(dat, split(text, sentence_id)), function(x) {
    strsplit(gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", as.character(x)), "\\s+")[[1]]
})

nms <- sort(unique(unlist(out)))

out2 <- lapply(out, function(x) {
    as.data.frame(table(x), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
})

dat2 <- data.frame(x = nms)

for(i in seq_along(out2)) {
    m <- merge(dat2, out2[[i]], all.x = TRUE)
    names(m)[i + 1] <- dat[["sentence_id"]][i]
    dat2 <- m
}

dat2[is.na(dat2)] <- 0
x <- as.matrix(dat2[, -1]) > 0

out3 <- x %*% t(x)
out3[upper.tri(out3, diag=TRUE)] <- NA
dimnames(out3) <- list(dat2[[1]], dat2[[1]])

out4 <- na.omit(data.frame( 
        word1 = rep(rownames(out3), ncol(out3)),  
        word2 = rep(colnames(out3), each = nrow(out3)),
        freq = c(unlist(out3)),
        stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
)

row.names(out4) <- NULL

out4
```

Comment: Thanks! Your approach might work for others' future research. However, my sentences are actually in Chinese, and the script seems not able to deal with Chinese characters. It turned all the characters into alphanumeric in a way I can't understand.

Comment: Can yu be specific?  What part turned them into alpha-numeric?

Comment: Oh I figure it out. The script doesn't turn Chinese chars into anything, it just omits them. The row.names of the matrix generated by `x <- t(mtabulate(with(dat, by(text, sentence_id, bag_o_words))) > 0)` are the English words/digits which are parts of the sentences.

Comment: I don't even know what `bag_o_words` is, but +1 on the alternatives. I've posted [a close relative of this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27164269/1270695) using `cSplit_e` from "splitstackshape" as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

This is very closely related to @TylerRinker's answer, but using different tools.

```
library(splitstackshape)
library(reshape2)

temp <- crossprod(
  as.matrix(
    cSplit_e(d, "text", " ", type = "character", 
             fill = 0, drop = TRUE)[-1]))
temp[upper.tri(temp, diag = TRUE)] <- NA
melt(temp, na.rm = TRUE)
#      Var1   Var2 value
# 2  text_b text_a     2
# 3  text_c text_a     1
# 4  text_d text_a     1
# 5  text_e text_a     3
# 8  text_c text_b     2
# 9  text_d text_b     2
# 10 text_e text_b     2
# 14 text_d text_c     2
# 15 text_e text_c     1
# 20 text_e text_d     1
```

The "text_" parts of "Var1" and "Var2" can be stripped easily with `sub` or `gsub`.

Comment: I like it.  I pulled out `spllitstackshape` today in an answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/27158031/1000343 but it got no love :-(

Comment: the approach seems simple and straight but R can't find function `cSplit`, `cSplit_e`, or `cSplit_f` in the latest manual. I guess it's because I installed splitstackshape 1.2.0 (binary version) by default, not 1.4.2 (Mac OSX 10.8.5, R 3.1.1). I tried `install.packages("splitstackshape", repos= "http://github.com/mrdwab/splitstackshape", type= "source")` but it said `package ‘splitstackshape’ is not available (for R version 3.1.1)`

Comment: @leoce, try installing it from CRAN but with `type = "source"`. You may also need to do the same for "data.table", perhaps before installing "splitstackshape".

Comment: @leoce, to install from GitHub, try using `install_github` from "devtools" -- something like `install_github("mrdwab/splitstackshape", ref = "devel")` should give you 1.4.3.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a base R way:

```
d <- read.table(text='sentence_id text
1           "a b c d e"
2           "a b b e"
3           "b c d"
4           "a e"', header=TRUE, as.is=TRUE)

result.vec <- table(unlist(lapply(d$text, function(text) {
    pairs <- combn(unique(scan(text=text, what='', sep=' ')), m=2)
    interaction(pairs[1,], pairs[2,])
})))
# a.b b.b c.b d.b a.c b.c c.c d.c a.d b.d c.d d.d a.e b.e c.e d.e 
#   2   0   0   0   1   2   0   0   1   2   2   0   3   2   1   1 

result <- subset(data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(names(result.vec), '\\.')), freq=as.vector(result.vec)), freq > 0)
with(result, result[order(X1, X2),])

#    X1 X2 freq
# 1   a  b    2
# 5   a  c    1
# 9   a  d    1
# 13  a  e    3
# 6   b  c    2
# 10  b  d    2
# 14  b  e    2
# 11  c  d    2
# 15  c  e    1
# 16  d  e    1
```

Comment: Thanks! In real data however, there might be 2 problems. I tried and find out that the script can't remove 1-word sentence like 'hah'. If a sentence has multiple words but they would be `unique` to 1 (like 'hah hah hah'), the console will raise error, too.

Comment: I've added a few lines here to deal with the problem above: http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6328674 , thanks!