# R and readLines of webpage text

Tags: r, readlines

I am wanting to create a single dataframe from the following website: http://www.arrs.net/MaraList/ML_2014.htm

Unfortunately I am not sure how to take what seem to be tab delimiters and create columns of data. The code I have below takes and creates multiple character strings but I'm having trouble determining how to separate names that have multiple words into a single column as it is shown on the site.

```
library(XML)
url<-"http://www.arrs.net/MaraList/ML_2014.htm"
data<-readLines(url)
data<-sub("</FONT></b><FONT SIZE=\"2\" <FONT COLOR=\"#00000\" FACE=\"Courier New,           Courier\">","",data)
data<-sub("<B><FONT COLOR=\"#0066FF\" FACE=\"Arial\">","",data)
data<-read.table(textConnection(data),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
data<-data[11:40000,1]
```

So, not sure any of the current code I have can get me there.  Any information or link(s) to prior posts would be appreciated.

Comment: That data does't appear to be delimited, it appears to be fixed width. You'll probably be better off using `read.fwf` but you're going to have to determine the column breaks yourself.

Comment: Completely agree with @MrFlick and you can just extract non tagged lines: `mara <- readLines(url); records <- grep("<", mara, invert=TRUE, value=TRUE); records <- grep("^[A-Z]", records, value=TRUE)`. I, too, shall leave you to character count :-)

Comment: Understandable, thanks for the help @MrFlick and hrbrmstr

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach to read this in (using two packages I maintain and the terrific `stacksplitshape` package) .  You'll need the dev version of `qdapTools`.

```
devtools::install_github("trinker/qdapTools")
library(qdapTools); library(qdapRegex); library(splitstackshape)
url<-"http://www.arrs.net/MaraList/ML_2014.htm"

m <- readLines(url)[-c(1:7, 2760:2767)]

## Split into lists by country    
x <- loc_split(m, unique(grep("<B><FONT", m)))

## Clean up country names
nms <- rm_angle(sapply(x, `[`, 1))

## remove html country name from data can convert to a data.frame
dat <- list2df(setNames(lapply(x, `[`, -1), nms), "dats", "Country")[, 2:1]

## Use hand parsing technique to locate widths      
## I added a # before each column in row one of data
## gregexpr tells us the location of the # characters
det <- "AAR  #26#Jan #King George Island           #      #27+25   #White Continent                        #4:03:30    #Steve Hibbs (USA)              #4:13:02    #Suzy Seeley (54,TX/USA) "
widths <- gregexpr("#", det)[[1]]

## replace those widths with # character as it is not any where else in data set
for (i in widths){
    substring(dat[["dats"]], i, i) <-  "#" 
}

## split columns on # character
out <- cSplit(dat, 2, sep="#")

out
```

Comment: `devtools("trinker/qdapTools")` ?

Comment: Thanks @TylerRinker, not familiar with those tools so I'll take a look.

Comment: @DirtyFilthyTerribleRaptor - I didn't have much time and haven't updated devtools in a while - there could have been an update that added a 'devtools' function but I also didn't see you loading devtools so I wasn't sure what was going on.