# Building a Co-Occurrence List in R around Selected Terms

Tags: r, nlp, text-mining, linguistics

I am trying to build a co-occurrence matrix (i. e., upper-triangle) of selected terms that appear in sentences.

My data is organized as:

```
sent_id text
1           a b c d e f g h i k l m n o p q
2           a d f k m n q
3           a c e l n o p
4           e f g h h m o q
5           b c f h i m n p
6           b d f h k m o q
```

The output I am desiring via R should look like:

```
    a   c   d   m   o
a  NA   2   2   2   2
c  NA  NA   1   2   2
d  NA  NA  NA   3   2
m  NA  NA  NA  NA   3
o  NA  NA  NA  NA  NA
```

That is, in the input sentences, I am only looking for co-occurrences of selected words (here, a, c, d, m and o).

I have searched the related questions on this topic.  The closest question/answer is: [build word co-occurence edge list in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27153320/build-word-co-occurence-edge-list-in-r)     .... from TylerRinker

This code works great for building a full co-occurrence matrix for all terms that appear in all sentences.  However, I don't know how to program the subset list of terms so that the co-occurrence matrix is built only around them (that is, a, c. d, m and o).  Any help or pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated.

Comment: Are you only stuck at subsetting? Similarly with the answers in your linked QA, something like `words = strsplit(as.character(DF$text), " "); DF2 = data.frame(id = rep(DF$sent_id, lengths(words)), word = unlist(words)); crossprod(table(droplevels(DF2[DF2$word %in% c("a", "c", "d", "m", "o"), ])))` seems to work - or is there a different problem?

Comment: Thank you Alexis!  Yes, the subsetting was the part that had me stuck.  Your code - especially the last line, did the trick...just what I was looking for.   I did not have experience with _crossprod_ before.  But, working twith the code, I learned about it.  Thank you for the help!...wonderful.